# How to pandas sort a dataframe that has one of the columns as version numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, distutils

I am a beginner in Python. I am trying to sort a dataframe on `versions` column -

`print(df)`

```
        versions         memory
0         10.0.0         107.07
1       10.0.0.1         110.11
2         10.0.2         110.56
3         10.0.4         116.27
4         10.1.0         116.17
5         10.1.2         113.98
6         10.1.4         113.27
7         10.2.0         103.32
8          9.9.2         112.02
9        9.9.2.3         112.28
10         9.9.4         114.45
11       9.9.4.1         114.32
```

such that the resulting dataframe is -

```
        versions         memory
0          9.9.2         112.02
1        9.9.2.3         112.28
2          9.9.4         114.45
3        9.9.4.1         114.32
4         10.0.0         107.07
5       10.0.0.1         110.11
6         10.0.2         110.56
7         10.0.4         116.27
8         10.1.0         116.17
9         10.1.2         113.98
10        10.1.4         113.27
11        10.2.0         103.32
```

The datatype of the `versions` columns is `object`.

I tried doing -

`df = df.sort_values('versions')`

But that leaves the dataframe unchanged.

Also tried doing -

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
df = sorted(df['ghost_version'], key=StrictVersion)
```

but it errors out on `ValueError: invalid version number '10.0.0.1'`

Can someone please guide?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create tuples filled by integers, get indices of sorted values by [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and change order by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), last for defaut index use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.iloc[df['versions'].apply(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split(".")))).argsort()]
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or use helper column with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last remove column:

```
df['tmp'] = df['versions'].apply(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split("."))))
df1 = df.sort_values('tmp').drop('tmp', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Also for order of sorted values is possible use `LooseVersion`:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

df1 = df.iloc[df['versions'].apply(LooseVersion).argsort()].reset_index(drop=True)


    versions  memory
0      9.9.2  112.02
1    9.9.2.3  112.28
2      9.9.4  114.45
3    9.9.4.1  114.32
4     10.0.0  107.07
5   10.0.0.1  110.11
6     10.0.2  110.56
7     10.0.4  116.27
8     10.1.0  116.17
9     10.1.2  113.98
10    10.1.4  113.27
11    10.2.0  103.32
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to re-reindex from ```0``` to ```11``` such that index for version ```9.9.2``` is 0 and so on?

Comment: @Ira - Use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @jezrael, this is great answer, thanks for sharing sir cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `distutils.version.LooseVersion`:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

df["versions"] = df["versions"].apply(LooseVersion)
new_df = df.sort_values("versions")
# new_df["version"] = new_df["verions"].astype(str)
# if you don't want to have LooseVersion objects
print(new_df)
```

Or from `pandas => 1.1.0`, `sort_values` can accept `key`, similar to that of `sorted`, but needs a vectorized callable.

```
f = lambda x: [LooseVersion(i) for i in x]
new_df = df.sort_values("versions", key=f)
print(new_df)
```

And if you want a brand new `RangeIndex`:

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output after re-indexing:

```
    versions  memory
0      9.9.2  112.02
1    9.9.2.3  112.28
2      9.9.4  114.45
3    9.9.4.1  114.32
4     10.0.0  107.07
5   10.0.0.1  110.11
6     10.0.2  110.56
7     10.0.4  116.27
8     10.1.0  116.17
9     10.1.2  113.98
10    10.1.4  113.27
11    10.2.0  103.32
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to re-index from ```0``` to ```11``` such that index for version ```9.9.2``` is 0 and so on?

Comment: @Ira Sure. Add a new line of `reset_index`. I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

```
df['nVersion'] = df['version'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x.split('.')[0]) + '.' + str(''.join(x.split('.')[1:]))))
```

After this you can sort the `nVersion` column and then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Giver column no instead of column name

```
df = df.sort_values('0')
```

Please look into this solution too

[How to pandas sort a dataframe that has one of the columns as version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113271/how-to-pandas-sort-a-dataframe-that-has-one-of-the-columns-as-version-numbers/64113392#64113362)